# How to prove rigourously that $f(x)=2x^3-15x^2+36x+1$ is surjective

Tags: calculus

We have a function $f:[0,3]\rightarrow [1,29]$, and $f(x)=2x^3-15x^2+36x+1$ and we need to prove it is surjective. Firstly I proved it as many-one function:

$f'(x)=6(x-2)(x-3)$, and $f(x)$ is increasing in $[0,2]$ and decreasing in $[2,3]$ so its consequently a many-one function. Now for surjective, I can't express this function in terms of $y$ easily. Another method I tried is very silly and not sure it is even correct:

I saw that $f(0)=1$, $f(2)=29, f(3)=28$, so its $f(x)$'s range might cover whole $[1,29]$, and it could be proved surjective, but again, I say that it isn't rigorous and possibly wrong. So, I need help here. Tell me if this method is wrong or correct also.

Comment: You found the values $1$ and $29$ and $f(x)$ is continous since it is a polynomial. The intermediate value theorem gives then immediately that every value in $[1,29]$ occurs.

Comment: Use the intermediate value theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Comment: What do you mean with "many-one" ? "not injective" ?

Comment: @Gribouillis Thanks for commenting. I didn't know of this theorem. Rest now it can be proved surjective with what I had done.

Comment: @Peter Yes. many-one function is used for describing non-injective functions

Comment: @KshitijKumar The theorem is a rigorous argument to say that if $1$ and $29$ are in the range of $f$, then $[1, 29]$ is in the range of $f$. In fact, it is exactly what the theorem says (because $f$ is continuous).

Comment: @Gribouillis Thank you very much for helping me out.